# Update Score based on interactive feedback for Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scoring, relevance

I am working on a project, which requires me to build a UI for a search engine. Elasticsearch is my choice. After indexing data and doing search queries, I also implement a function so that, if the user ticks on a result that is not relevant, I will reduce the score of that specific data in elasticsearch. However, when doing the second search with the same query, the order of search results remained the same. The reason is that even though the score is updated, the order of the data in elasticsearch index remained unchanged.
How do I reflect the score changes without having to reindex the whole thing again?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bool / should query. There you perform a term query with a boosting.

This is how you change the order depending on the search.

Comment: I actually have used bool match query. So the boosting can solve this?